# Как выбрать значение из json?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, boost

Вот json:

```
{
    "ts": 1827908701,
    "updates": [
        [4, 30623409, 17, 81282347579, 1425823449632, " ... ", "tfs"],
        [80, 1, 0],
        [7, 81282347579, 30652308]
    ]
}
```

Как мне взять значение, например, 4, из updates с помощью библиотеки boost?

Comment: Использовать `Boost.PropertyTree` и `json_parser`. Примерно как показано в [доке](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html).

Comment: Я знаю, как взять, например, значение из "ts". Но не понимаю, как взять значение из двух квадратных скобок и без key.

Comment: @maza51 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206705/reading-json-file-with-boost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, `Boost.PropertyTree` не умеет в индексирование массивов. Поэтому надо их перебирать:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "{\"ts\":1827908701,\"updates\":[[4,30623409,17,812823,14258234,\"tfs\"],[80,1,0],[7,81282347579,30652308]]}";
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);
std::cout << pt.get<int>("ts") << std::endl;

BOOST_FOREACH(auto &v, pt.get_child("updates"))
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(auto &w, v.second)
    {
        std::cout << w.second.data() << std::endl; // тут мы вытащим и 4, и 30623409 и "tfs"    
    }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо. А как мне теперь узнать тогда, с какого именно поля я вытащил?
Создавать цикл и отчитывать?

Comment: цикл уже создан, переменную заведи и считай

Comment: @maza51, именно так. Хотите вытащить, например, 3й элемент - считаете в цикле до 3х